# Why is my style not being applied to a non-HTML element in IE?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

This doesn't work in IE6 or 7:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        N {display: block}
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <N>element1</N>
        <N>element2</N>
        <N>element3</N>
        <N>element4</N>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

however, it does if I replace the N tags with A tags.

Does IE have a problem with styling non-HTML tags? Or is it something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Does IE have a problem with styling
>   non-HTML tags?

Yes. It won't.

You *could* hack it using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.createElement('n');
</script>
```

… but that won't work if JS is not available and the document is still invalid.

If no element exists that describes the semantics you want, then use the one that matches most closely (or div/span if nothing better exists) and add classes.

(Or switch to a custom XML language)

Comment: Spot on. The hack will do nicely for now!